# Eigen not found

Tags: calibration, eigen, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying to install [industrial_calibration](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_calibration/tree/indigo-devel) (Indigo branch) but I keep getting the following error:

> Could not find a package
> configuration file provided by "Eigen"
> with any of   the following names:
>
> ```
> EigenConfig.cmake
> eigen-config.cmake
> ```

I can fix it by changing Eigen to Eigen3 in CMakefiles.txt but then I get a lot of errors during the build.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196100/eigen-not-found/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `CMakeLists.txt` (and package manifest) are missing a dependency declaration on the `cmake_modules` package. In Hydro, `catkin` itself provided the required config files, but in Indigo they have moved, resulting in the error you see. See also [indigo/Migration - cmake_modules](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration#cmake_modules) on the ROS wiki.

To get things working quickly:

- Update the `find_package(catkin ..)` invocation and append `cmake_modules` to the end.
- Also add a `build_depend` on `cmake_modules` to the `package.xml` file.

---

Edit: reported the issue, see [industrial_calibration/issues/31](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_calibration/issues/31).

---

Edit2: [PR 38](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_calibration/pull/38) is meant to fix these issues (missing `cmake_modules` and the `yaml-cpp` incompatibilities).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-10-28**:
You already reported the same issue in July, see [#31](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_calibration/issues/31)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-28**:
Seems you're right. Probably a bit too early still for me :). It has become a bit more urgent now though.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-10-28**:
And what about the yaml-cpp problem? it still doesn't compile because of that on 14.04